# Loading Map Markers by bounding box, but they are spilling out east of viewport

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading in Map Markers to Google Maps API (v3) by checking if they are within the map.getBounds(), then using that data to filter an SQL query. It's working great, apart from the marker loading only seems to be bound by the North and South edges of the viewport - When I pan left or right there are still markers populated to the east <s>and west</s> of my initial viewport position.

[image: First Viewport]
[image: Zoomed out view]

As you can see, all possible markers are being loaded along east/west, even when they aren't in the original bounding box.

PHP/MySQL:

```
function get_addresses_from_bounds($swLat = null, $swLong = null, $neLat = null, $neLong = null) {
    if(!$swLat || !$swLong || !$neLat || !$neLong) {
        return;
    }

    $q_where = [];

    $q = "SELECT `latitude`, `longitude` FROM `customer_cards` as `c` INNER JOIN `geo_location` as `g` ON `g`.`placename` = `c`.`delivery_postcode`";

    //Bounds
    $q_where[] = ":swLat < :neLat AND `latitude` BETWEEN :swLat AND :neLat) OR (:neLat < :swLat AND `latitude` BETWEEN :neLat AND :swLat";
    $q_where[] = ":swLong < :neLong AND `longitude` BETWEEN :swLong AND :neLong) OR (:neLong < :swLong AND `longitude` BETWEEN :neLong AND :swLong";

    if(!empty($q_where)) {
        $q .= ' WHERE ( ' . implode(' ) && ( ', $q_where) . ')';
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($q);

    // Assign variables
    $stmt->bindParam(':swLat', $swLat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':swLong', $swLong, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':neLat', $neLat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':neLong', $neLong, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $members = $stmt->fetchAll();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($members); $i++) {
        unset($members[$i][0]);
        unset($members[$i][1]);
    }

    return $members;
}
```

**Update:** By using a simpler WHERE to select the bounds, it has partially fixed my problem. It is now only spilling out to the east, west of the screen bounds are fine.

```
WHERE `latitude` > :swLat AND `latitude` < :neLat AND `longitude` > :swLong AND `longitude` < :neLong
```

**Update 2**: I got it working with the above query, not sure how because it was at the end of a long day of head bashing. So I haven't added this as an answer

Comment: Seems you don't recall the markers loading/poulation when you pan/zoom ....please show also the code (javascript)  where you render the marker and invoke php function

Comment: @scaisEdge I removed some functions from my code snippets for brevity's sake, the marker functions and other snippets are visible in my revisions though http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33999622/revisions

Comment: what's the data-type of the latitude- and longitude-columns? Note that when it's a string-type you compare 2 strings, e.g. `2` then would be greater than `12`